# How to fix my grado headphones?

Tags: headphones, electronics, repair

Not sure if this is the right forum- I was initially thinking electronics.stackexchange, but I have a feeling this is more specific to this forum.

My trusty old SR80s have served me well, and still do, but the plastic shielding around the cable for one of the cans has been stripped off.

They still sound fine, but when I turn my head or move slightly sometimes I here muffled scratching coming out of the can with the damaged cable.

Here is what I'm working with:
[image]

How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

- Open your headphones.
- Strongly resolder your cables.
- Add some electric tape around your wire
- Close back your headphones.

here are videos that show you  how to open Grado SR-60:

- [video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yth-7k1fbGg)
- [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JHGJqfM0wE)

I guess this must be close to the way to open the SR-80 model.

Comment: Well thats kinda my question. I don't know how to open them up- there aren't any screws and don't want to break the plastic trying to pry it open.

Comment: I used a set of these on loan a while back.  Nice headphones.  Although I didn't check, it is the case with many things in this world are "assembled once; disassembled never".  That usually involves non-obvious plastic clips.

Consequently, you must make a decision:  Are you prepared for some minor cosmetic damage in the interests of fixing a serious electrical problem?